# Bootstrap datetimepicker stepping issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have two linked Bootstrap datetimepickers. Here's the code for them:

```
var d = new Date();
var one_month = d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) + 1 );

$(function () {
    $('#pick1').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en',
            sideBySide: true,
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            minDate: new Date(),
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            stepping: 15
    });

    $('#pick2').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en',
            sideBySide: true,
            defaultDate: one_month,
            minDate: new Date(),
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            stepping: 15
    });

    $('#pick1').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            $('#pick2').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);
    });
    $('#pick2').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            $('#pick1').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having is that dependent on the time now, one of the pickers (usually `pick1`) doesn't display the default date.

Here's a jsFiddle to illustrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xbt5wa9/1/

(If it looks okay, run it again after a few minutes)

I think this issue is related to the `stepping` option, this is only because if you comment it out, it fixes the issue.

It also appears as though the issue is related to the beginning of the stepping figure. So, if `stepping` is set to 15; minutes 15, 16, 17 will have the issue, but towards 30 it will not. I haven't tested this hypothesis to conclusion, life's too short.

Can anyone help? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I never got to the bottom of it. Apologies for the delay. Please post if you found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just ran into this exact problem, the issue has been raised on the plugins [GitHub Page](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1065) and still looks like this bug is yet to be fixed.

> The reason why it happens is because the stepper rounds to the nearest
>   value. So sometimes this will mean rounding down to the nearest 15
>   which can be before `minDate = moment()`.
>
> Example: 11:18am will round down to 11:15am but this is before `moment()`
>   making it invalid.
>
> This explanation is courtesy of the GitHub issue raiser.

The issue raiser goes on to provide a hacky workaround which I'm unsure how reliable it is. Maybe this issue is still being resolved but it was raised a while ago!

I thought I would share this information with everybody (even if this is an old question!) as there doesn't some to be a lot of help out there about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('#pick1').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en',
            sideBySide: true,
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            minDate: new Date(),
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            stepping: 15
    });

    $('#pick2').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en',
            sideBySide: true,                  
            minDate: new Date(),
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            stepping: 15
    });

    $('#pick1').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            $('#pick2').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);
    });
    $('#pick2').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            $('#pick1').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```